# Convergence for "general" version of Riemann zeta function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

Let $\{u_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a non-decreasing sequence of positive reals limiting to infinity.

We define the "general" Riemann zeta sum for $\{u_k\}_k$ by
$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (u_k)^{-s}
$.

We denote by $S \subset \mathbb{C}$ the set of $s \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the sum above converges.

My question is, in general what does $S$ look like? We know for $u_k = k$ that $S$ is a right half-plane $\{\mathrm{Re}s>1\}$. In general can we say $S$ is a right half-plane, to the right of the imaginary axis?

Note: a result like this seems to be used just after equation (1.20) in [this paper](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/detsur.pdf) of Dan Freed. Of course, there are probably more constraints on $\lambda_k = u_k$ in the situation given in the paper than I've put here, but I was wondering how general the result used is. I tried taking a look at the paper which is cited as [Se] after equation (1.20) in Dan Freed's paper, but I couldn't really understand it enough to extract the above statement.

Comment: With a change of variables, so you have $e^{v_n}=u_n$ these are general Dirichlet series and their theory is studied for example in Hardy's book on the subject (there is an abscissa of convergence though of course it may  be infinite like for $u_k=\log k, k \ge 2$ which doesn't converge for any $s$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $S$ to be a right half-plane, it is sufficient to have $u_k=r_ke^{i\theta}$ for some fixed argument $\theta$, and have moduli $r_k \geq 1$. Then for any $s=x+yi$ we have

$$ \bigg \vert \sum_k u_k^{-s} \bigg \vert = \bigg \vert \sum_k r_k^{-s}e^{-i\theta s} \bigg \vert = \bigg \vert \sum_k r_k^{-x}e^{-yi} e^{-i\theta s} \bigg \vert = \bigg \vert e^{-yi} e^{-i\theta s} \sum_k r_k^{-x} \bigg \vert = \sum_k r_k^{-x}. $$

This shows that the modulus of $\sum_k u_k^{-s}$ is independent of $\text{Im}s$ and decreasing in $x$, which means that the set where the modulus is finite is a right half-plane.

Note that if we drop the requirement that $r_k \geq 1$, we can easily get a left half-plane, e.g. by $u_k=k^{-1}$. I cannot come up with an example of any $u_k$ which don't give a left or right half-plane, so the necessary conditions are likely weaker than mine.

Comment: In the OP $u_k >0$ increasing (not necessary strictly) to infinity so we have a right half-plane of convergence by general theory - it may be empty as $u_k=\log k, k \ge 2$ shows  (this is clear since $(\log k)^{-a} \ge k^{-1}, k \ge k(a)$ large enough for any $a>0$

Comment: @Conrad Perhaps $u_k=\log(k+1)$ would be a better example since it's defined at $k=1$?

Comment: @Steven doesn't really matter since the behavior depends only on the large values of $k$ so one can take $u_1 >0$ anything (less than $\log 2$ if one wants to keep non-decreasing which also matters only for $k$ large enough)